# Custom UIButton hard to press

Tags: iphone, uibutton, png

If I add a basic UIButton all is well, they are always easy to press every time. However, when I make a custom version using my own .png it becomes hard to trigger every time.

My custom button is a little smaller 32x32 and is mostly transparent. Could it simply be that its smaller, could the transparency be a problem..?

many thanks for any thoughts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is because it's smaller than 32x32, try making your transparency layer a little bigger, say 40x40 to have a bigger hit area. I mean use a bigger PNG :)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have overhided any touches method and not called super in it...
Keep the frame of the view to 40*40 and clear the background color then set the image which is 32*32... It will work correctly

Comment: I don't think I have, and besides all I have done is change an already working fine default uibutton to 'custom' and updated the size.